# Recursive function with sum of count of each child SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, recursion

I'm new here, so please accept my apologize if there is a rule that I ignored it.

I use SQL Server 2005.

I have a table which contains a parent-child structured tree.

There is a query that scans above mentioned tree. There is also another tree including some of children of the 1st table. Each child of 1st table could be repeated for more than 1 time in the 2nd table.

*1st table (called `TBL1`):*

```
CID    Parent_ID    Seq_NO    CName 
650    NULL            1        A 
135    650             1        B 
950    135             1        C 
124    135             2        D 
725    135             3        E 
421    135             4        F 
632    421             1        G 
906    421             2        H 
119    421             3        I 
215    650             2        J 
436    215             1        K 
150    215             2        L 
260    150             1        M 
501    260             1        N 
154    260             2        O 
132    260             3        P 
721    150             2        Q 
960    215             3        R
```

*Query for scannning the tree of `TBL1`*

```
WITH SCAN_TREE(IID, QName, Parent_ID, levleTREE, HRName, SO) AS  
( 
   SELECT 
       CID, CName, Parent_ID,  
       0 AS initlvl,  
       CAST(INIT_POINT.CName AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS initName, 
       CAST(INIT_POINT.Seq_NO AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS initSO 
   FROM TBL1 AS INIT_POINT 
   WHERE (INIT_POINT.CID=650) 

   UNION ALL 

   SELECT 
       LOOP_Q.CID, LOOP_Q.CName, LOOP_Q.Parent_ID,  
       FINAL_Q.levleTREE + 1 AS looplvl,  
       CAST(FINAL_Q.HRName + '-' + LOOP_Q.CName AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS loopName, 
       CAST(FINAL_Q.SO + CAST(LOOP_Q.Seq_NO AS BINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS loopSO 
   FROM TBL1 AS LOOP_Q 
   INNER JOIN SCAN_TREE AS FINAL_Q ON LOOP_Q.Parent_ID = FINAL_Q.IID 
 ) 
 SELECT 
     LAST_Q.IID, LAST_Q.QName, LAST_Q.Parent_ID, LAST_Q.levleTREE, LAST_Q.HRName 
 FROM SCAN_TREE AS LAST_Q  
 ORDER BY SO
```

The output of above query:*

```
IID     QName  Parent_ID   levleTREE    HRName 
650       A      NULL        0           A 
135       B      650         1           A-B 
950       C      135         2           A-B-C 
124       D      135         2           A-B-D 
725       E      135         2           A-B-E 
421       F      135         2           A-B-F 
632       G      421         3           A-B-F-G 
906       H      421         3           A-B-F-H 
119       I      421         3           A-B-F-I 
215       J      650         1           A-J 
436       K      215         2           A-J-K 
150       L      215         2           A-J-L 
260       M      150         3           A-J-L-M 
501       N      260         4           A-J-L-M-N 
154       O      260         4           A-J-L-M-O 
132       P      260         4           A-J-L-M-P 
721       Q      150         3           A-J-L-Q 
960       R      215         2           A-J-R
```

*2nd table (called `TBL2`):*

```
MID
----
950
124
124
632v
632
632
421
```

What I want is the sum of all occurance of each child of 1nd table in 2nd table for each parent of 1st table.

I need a query to retrieve below result, actually I need first column (`MID`):

```
MID  IID  QName Parent_ID levleTREE HRName
7    650  A     NULL      0         A
7    135  B     650       1         A-B
1    950  C     135       2         A-B-C
2    124  D     135       2         A-B-D
0    725  E     135       2         A-B-E
4    421  F     135       2         A-B-F
3    632  G     421       3         A-B-F-G
0    906  H     421       3         A-B-F-H
0    119  I     421       3         A-B-F-I
0    215  J     650       1         A-J
0    436  K     215       2         A-J-K
0    150  L     215       2         A-J-L
0    260  M     150       3         A-J-L-M
0    501  N     260       4         A-J-L-M-N
0    154  O     260       4         A-J-L-M-O
0    132  P     260       4         A-J-L-M-P
0    721  Q     150       3         A-J-L-Q
0    960  R     215       2         A-J-R
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You ignored the rule about not apologizing in advance for ignoring The Rules! ;)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: How is MID calculated?  The first row of the desired result shows `mid = 7`... where does the `7` come from?

Comment: to Andmor: for node G we have 3 row in TBL2. and for F wee have 1 directly. Some of child and grand child for node F is 1+3 = 4

Answer (score 2):

You can do a few standard left joins here:

```
WITH SCAN_TREE(IID, QName, Parent_ID, levleTREE, HRName, SO, MID) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        CID, 
        CName, 
        Parent_ID, 
        0 AS initlvl, 
        CAST(INIT_POINT.CName AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS initName,
        CAST(INIT_POINT.Seq_NO AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS initSO,
        COUNT(T2.MID) as MID
    FROM 
        TBL1 AS INIT_POINT
        LEFT JOIN TBL2 AS T2 ON
            INIT_POINT.CID = T2.MID
    WHERE
        INIT_POINT.CID=650
    GROUP BY
        CID,
        CName,
        ParentId,
        Seq_NO
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        LOOP_Q.CID, 
        LOOP_Q.CName, 
        LOOP_Q.Parent_ID, 
        FINAL_Q.levleTREE + 1 AS looplvl, 
        CAST(FINAL_Q.HRName + '-' + LOOP_Q.CName AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS loopName,
        CAST(FINAL_Q.SO + CAST(LOOP_Q.Seq_NO AS BINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS loopSO,
        COUNT(T2.MID) as MID
    FROM 
        TBL1 AS LOOP_Q 
        INNER JOIN SCAN_TREE AS FINAL_Q ON 
            LOOP_Q.Parent_ID = FINAL_Q.IID
        LEFT JOIN TBL2 AS T2 ON
            LOOP_Q.CID = T2.MID
    GROUP BY
        LOOP_Q.CID, 
        LOOP_Q.CName, 
        LOOP_Q.Parent_ID, 
        FINAL_Q.levleTREE,
        FINAL_Q.HRName,
        FINAL_Q.SO,
        FINAL_Q.Seq_NO
)

SELECT
    LAST_Q.IID, 
    LAST_Q.QName, 
    LAST_Q.Parent_ID, 
    LAST_Q.levleTREE, 
    LAST_Q.HRName,
    SUM(T2.MID) as MID
FROM 
    SCAN_TREE AS LAST_Q
    LEFT JOIN SCAN_TREE as CHILDREN ON
        CHILDREN.HRName like LAST_Q.HRName + '%'
GROUP BY
    LAST_Q.IID, 
    LAST_Q.QName, 
    LAST_Q.Parent_ID, 
    LAST_Q.levleTREE, 
    LAST_Q.HRName
order by SO
```

All we're doing is joining `TBL2` to `TBL1` based on when the `CID` column equals the `MID` column. Then, we're counting the number of results we get. Since a `left join` will give us a `null` value for the `MID` column if one doesn't exist, we can rely on this for counting--`null` equals `0` to `count`. Next, outside of the CTE, we just join the CTE to itself and sum up those counts where the `HRName` (a nice hierarchy) begins with the given `HRName`, so `A-B-C` will grab the `MID` of `A-B-C`, `A-B-C-D`, `A-B-C-D-E`, and `A-B-C-J`, for example.

Comment: Thank you, but I need sum of child and grand chiled in each level. e.g. for node B result must be 7 or for nod F the result must be 4.

Comment: Updated to give you what you're looking for--sorry, didn't understand what you were looking for at first.

Comment: I drow a picture of the tree and explained my question, but I can't upload it because I'm new user. How can I send it to you?

Comment: Thank you for your kind cooperation. But I get some errors: 
`Server: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 20`

`Invalid column name 'ParentId'.`

`Server: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 44`

`Invalid column name 'Seq_NO'.`

`Server: Msg 467, Level 16, State 1, Line 44`

`GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate functions are not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'SCAN_TREE'.`

`Server: Msg 462, Level 16, State 1, Line 44`

`Outer join is not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'SCAN_TREE'.`